# Juniper Network Connect couldn't connect to server

Tags: networking, network-interface, network-connection

I'm facing connection issues with `Juniper Network connect 6.3` to connect to our University Linux server. I'm unable to connect to the server, I assume there might be some issues with Network Connect application because I'm able to connect from other machines. After entering my credentials, the status in the session menu shows reconnecting and never gets connected.

When I try to perform the diagnostics, the result was:

[image]

I'm not sure why it is not working as expected. I tried re-installng, but in first trail it worked and re-opening it doesn't.

Did anyone come across this issue? Is there any permanent solution for this issue??

OS: Windows 7 (installed through VM)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstalling the current version + deleting the directory and reinstalling solved the problem. Wish it would help someone facing this kind of issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have a reverse proxy setup using fiddler. I have to shut down fiddler and then vpn in to my work, then I can restart fiddler. Probably not applicable to this thread, but maybe will help someone else.